# Convert VB6 Dbl Date value to Java Long Value

Tags: java, date, vb6, type-conversion

I have an old legacy VB6 application that is sending me a date value as a double via a `CDbl(Now)` type statement. On the java side, the current code reads in the value as `new Date(Long.parse(value))`.

I cannot modify the java side, but can change the VB6 code. How would I go about getting the correct floating point value for `Long.parse` to parse the value correct with the date and time.

I think that the java dates start at 0 on some arbitrary date counting up from there (1/1/1970 I think), the VB 6 date would probably be the same type of idea, but I'm finding it difficult to track down that information about the VB6 data types. Presumably if I knew what the difference between the dates are, and the units of measurement were the same I could just offset the value I send to the java application.

Comment: If I recall correctly, VB6 uses OLE date/time (`VT_DATE`). This article may get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476192/how-is-variant-time-date-double-8-byte-handled

Comment: Here's another one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/16/eric-s-complete-guide-to-vt-date.aspx

Comment: @xxbbcc Nice!, This may have what I need in it... a lot to read... at least its a start

Comment: Use CLng instead of CDbl... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

Comment: Don't use `CLng` - `Long` is a 32-bit integer in VB6. If you need to access the actual bytes of the value, you can use `VarPtr()`.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can try is calling [`VariantTimeToSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221440%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on the VB6 side and package the resulting `SYSTEMTIME` structure into a `Double`, following the date/time encoding rules of Java. (I don't know those rules, so I assume that they're different from the OLE date/time encoding rules. If they're the same, you can just pass the `Double` directly.)

If you need to directly access the bytes of the date value in VB6, you can call [`VarPtr()`](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/varptr.asp) - this gives you the address of the variable and you can read the bytes as you need. It may be safer than calling `CDbl()`. (I don't have VB6 installed at the moment but conversion functions may perform funny tricks on the input values. Calling `VariantTimeToSystemTime` avoids the need for `CDbl()`.)

Comment: This is where I was headed, I will do some testing, and get back to ya here

Comment: Thanks xxbbcc, I got back on this today and your documentation did lead me to a solution. I ended up just calculating the milliseconds from the java epoch date to the date in question, then doing some work to account for daylight savings time. Now I have correct dates on the java side. I would accept, but this wasn't quite the solution. Nevertheless it helped me get there.

Comment: @MarkW I'm glad you found a solution.