# Getting a timestamp from a file on an Android device

Tags: android, winapi, timestamp, visual-foxpro

I have a device running Android 11 connected to my Windows 7 laptop via USB cable.  I can see the device using Windows Explorer and drill down through the folders.  The file names, types, and modify dates all show up nicely in Explorer.  I'm writing software in Visual Foxpro which will put the file list into a listbox and allow the user to select which ones to copy to the PC.  When I run it, the names and types are good but the date shows up as a zero date which in VFP shows up as 12/30/1899 00:00:00.

The code I'm using looks something like this ("iX14" is the name of the Android device) :

```
        * Search the PC's namespace for the iX14 folder and set the name space variable
        oFOLDER = oSHELLAPP.Namespace("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}")
        for each oITEM in oFOLDER.Items
            if oITEM.Name = "iX14"
                mNAMESPACE = oITEM.Path 
                exit
            endif
        next

        * reset oFOLDER to the particular folder in the iX14 which has the files we need
        oFOLDER = oShellApp.Namespace(mNAMESPACE + "\Internal shared storage\Download\AutoLog")
        for each oITEM in oFOLDER.Items 
            thisform.listbox.AddItem(oITEM.ModifyDate)
```

At this point I have nowhere else to go since I'm a database guy and my focus is within databases and I know very little about using the Win32API and other OS level tasks.  I tried stepping through using the debugger to try to see exactly what was being returned from oITEM.ModifyDate but the debugger just shows up what I'm already getting, 12/30/1899 00:00:00.

Comment: I know nothing about Android nor Visual Foxpro. What I can say is the ModifyDate you're getting corresponds to this property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folderitem-modifydate which is of type DATE (in C/C++) which is a double (8-bytes) value sometimes called "variant date/time": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oaut/35c9bf2d-b8e8-4d7d-a50f-367da0d99fce More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476192/how-is-variant-time-date-double-8-byte-handled

Comment: And, I forgot to say, "12/30/1899 00:00:00" is exactly a DATE double with the 8 bytes set to 0. So it's a conversion issue.

Comment: It seems like the value is empty being processed as 0 internally which is  12/30/1899 00:00:00. I am having a hard time to explain it I know, it is like passing an empty date from VFP to say SQL server which doesn't have an understanding of empty date, converted to "MS' epoch date".

Comment: What exactly do you see in explorer screen? Would you mind to share?

Comment: The confusing thing to me is that Windows knows how to interpret an Android date/time since Explorer shows it correctly.  But when using a Windows API function, I seem to be getting back a zero.  It doesn't seem to be time zone or interpretation question.  I can go ahead and copy these files with the program I've written and the timestamp shows up correctly after being copied.  But I wanted to include the timestamp of the Android file in the list box to make it easier for the user to decide which file(s) to copy.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I would put a screenshot but I don't see how to do it here

Comment: OK no problem, you said you already see datetimes in explorer right. I am thinking of handling it via something else (filer maybe).

Comment: Yes, Explorer correctly shows file name, modify date, type, and size.  I just looked to see how it would show file size and file size also comes back as zero.  So it seems like it's a problem getting numbers using the win32api.

Comment: I added some code for testing. It uses Filer.dll that ships with VFP. You should already have it registered since Tools\Filer use the same dll.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please test this code on your system:

```
Local mNAMESPACE
oShellApp = Createobject("shell.application")
* Search the PC's namespace for the iX14 folder and set the name space variable
oFOLDER = oShellApp.Namespace("::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}")
For Each oITEM In oFOLDER.Items
    If oITEM.Name = "iX14"
        mNAMESPACE = oITEM.Path
        Exit
    Endif
Next

If !Empty(m.mNAMESPACE)

    Local lcPath
    lcPath = Addbs(m.mNAMESPACE) + "Internal shared storage\Download\AutoLog"
    GetTree(m.lcPath, '*.*')

    Select ;
        cast(filepath As Varchar(250)) As filepath, ;
        cast(filename As Varchar(250)) As filename, ;
        filesize, fattr, createtime, lastacc, lastwrite ;
        From filelist ;
        ORDER By 1,2
Endif

Function GetTree
    Lparameters tcStartDir, tcSkeleton
    tcSkeleton = Evl(m.tcSkeleton, "*.*")
    Create Cursor filelist ;
        (filepath m, filename m, filesize i, ;
        fattr c(8), createtime T, lastacc T, lastwrite T)

    oFiler = Createobject('filer.fileutil')
    With oFiler
        .SearchPath = m.tcStartDir
        .Subfolder = 1
        .FileExpression = m.tcSkeleton
        .Find(0)
        For ix=1 To .Files.Count
            With .Files(ix)

                Insert Into filelist ;
                    (filepath, filename, filesize, fattr, createtime, lastacc, lastwrite)  ;
                    values ;
                    (.Path, .Name, .Size, Attr2Char(.Attr), ;
                    Num2Time2(.Datetime), Num2Time2(.LastAccessTime), Num2Time2(.LastWriteTime) )

            Endwith
        Endfor
        Return .Files.Count
    Endwith
Endfunc

Function Num2Time2
    Lparameters tnFloat
    Return Dtot(Date(1899,12,30) + m.tnFloat)
Endfunc

Function Attr2Char
    Lparameters tnAttr
    Return ;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,0),'RO','RW')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,1),'H','_')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,2),'S','_')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,4),'D','_')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,5),'A','_')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,6),'E','_')+;
        IIF(Bittest(m.tnAttr,7),'N','_')
Endfunc
```

Comment: I suppose you can call dll export from Visual Foxpro , in this case you can use this API to convert the result from oITEM.ModifyDate into a string (BSTR) with  VarBstrFromDate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-varbstrfromdate

Comment: @SimonMourier, sorry but I didn't understand why one should do that. That is directly usable from VFP as shown in the code.

Comment: in GetTree, oFiler.Files.Count returns 0 so nothing goes into filelist.

Comment: @DougCLind, so you can't also use Tools\Filer using that path, right?

Comment: You just need to convert a DATE which is what's returned by the Shell API in ModifyDate into a string, you don't need to get back to file API plus the Shell is not always about physical files.

Comment: @SimonMourier, sorry I can't still see the point of converting 12/30/1899 00:00:00 to string. It is the problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier actually the VFP listbox requires each item to be a string so I do use a time-to-string function as in .AddItem( ttoc(oITEM.ModifyDate)).  Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @DougCLind, that would add '12/30/1899 00:00:00' (and actually you don't need any conversion if you use a RowSourceType of SQL - or alias).

Comment: @CetinBasoz sorry but I don't understand what  you mean by Tools\Filer.  Filer does not appear in the Tools dropdown.  I did step through the code and everything looked good but .files.count returns zero.  I looked up the Help files on filer so I could see that what you were doing should have been good.  But ...

Comment: @CetinBasoz I ran filer from "do form (home(1) + 'Tools\Filer\Filer.scx')" and this is the problem: the android device doesn't appear with a drive letter and I don't see a way to map it to drive. This is why I turned to the Win32API for a way to read and copy the files because VFP seems to need to refer to a drive letter.

Comment: @DougCLind, it is unfortunate I don't have any android device to test this. Sorry. (Might that make a difference to start the path with double backslashes?)